# Problems on evaluating Kotlin inside JVM with javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

Tags: kotlin, jvm, eval, meta-inf

I'm trying to evaluate Kotlin code inside JVM using the Java Scripting API.

```
try {
    ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts").let {
        it.eval("val f: (CommandContext.()->Any?) = {\n${this.args.joinToString(" ")}\n}; return f") as (CommandContext.()->Any?)
    }().let { embed.setDescription(it.toString()) }
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    embed.setColor(Color.RED)
    embed.setDescription(StringWriter().also { ex.printStackTrace(PrintWriter(it)) }.toString())
}
```

But... `ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")` is returning me a null value. I already added the `META-INF/services` file:

File Name: `javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory`

File Content: `org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory`

It sould work according to JetBrains: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed by adding

```
compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler:1.3.11'
compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.11'
compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util:1.3.11'
compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.11'
```

to my `build.gradle`.

**PS:** 1.3.11 is my Kotlin version.

Comment: Also, this didn't work for me with Maven and Kotlin version `1.3.31`. :(

Comment: tested and compiler not compilern worked for me.  Also to be more clear WRT the location of the services file, it goes in .../<module_name>/src/main/resources/META-INF/services, where .../<module_name>/src/main/java/... gets you to your .kt source files

Answer (score 4):

Adding a follow up because I was getting the same error but after getting the dependencies for 1.3.31 and added the script engine initialization file I was able to get it working.

My working dependencies:

```
plugins {
    base
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.31"
}
...

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
    compile(kotlin("reflect"))
    compile(kotlin("script-runtime"))
    compile(kotlin("compiler-embeddable"))
    compile(kotlin("script-util"))
    runtime(kotlin("scripting-compiler-embeddable"))

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0")

}
```

You definitely need to add the file src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory.

Here is the example file:
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/c2b5c1178165c1a4820d155f3ab1a7496a621dd3/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory

This chunk of code should show that you have the kotlin extension registered.

```
ScriptEngineManager().engineFactories.forEach { println(it.extensions)
...
[kts]
[js]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting around Kotlin 1.3.31 or 1.4, this seems to be enough in build.gradle.kts:

```
implementation(kotlin("scripting-jsr223"))
```

Answer (score 0):

the working version nowadays is simply:

```kotlin
runtimeOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223:${Deps.JetBrains.Kotlin.VERSION}")
```

which pulls in all necessary dependencies transitively.

Also the `META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory` File seems not to be necessary if doing so.